# Merge 2 images onto new image: can someone explain this code?

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to write a code to merge 2 photos side by side onto a new image, and I found this script online--however, I have no idea how it works.  Where do I input the image files that I want to merge?  Can someone please explain this code to me?  Thanks!!

```
from PIL import Image
import sys

if not len(sys.argv) > 3:
    raise SystemExit("Usage: %s src1 [src2] .. dest" % sys.argv[0])

images = map(Image.open, sys.argv[1:-1])
w = sum(i.size[0] for i in images)
mh = max(i.size[1] for i in images)

result = Image.new("RGBA", (w, mh))

x = 0
for i in images:
    result.paste(i, (x, 0))
    x += i.size[0]

result.save(sys.argv[-1])
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a tutorial-writing service.

Comment: My apologies.  I have been trying to find a working program to perform this function for a few weeks, so I was ecstatic to figure out how this works.

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy. You open the images with names provided in sys.argv (arguments to the program):

```
images = map(Image.open, sys.argv[1:-1])
```

You calculate the new width (sum of all width for opened images, which is i.size[0])

```
w = sum(i.size[0] for i in images)
```

The height, which should be equal to the height of the highest image (this way it can fit each)

```
mh = max(i.size[1] for i in images)
```

Create an image with calculated dumentions

```
result = Image.new("RGBA", (w, mh))
```

For each image opened, insert it (with `paste` function) to the point of x pixels from the left and 0 from the top and add the width of inserted image to x so that the next one is adjacent, not overlapping

```
x = 0
for i in images:
    result.paste(i, (x, 0))
    x += i.size[0]
```

Save the image

```
result.save(sys.argv[-1])
```

The error processing you see at the top has nothing to do with the process of merging images, but rather asserts that there is a correct number of arguments to the program